# How to isolate guest and host CPU real time clocks?

Tags: qemu, kvm

I want to implement a mechanism to test the performance of a custom Linux kernel driver. To do so, I am implementing a hardware PCIe device on QEMU. So far, so good, the guest kernel belives that my device is attached and my kernel module behalf as expected.

In order to do my performance testing, I have to fill several buffers on host side, and that demmands quite some processing time, so I need that the guest operating system do not forward the real time while the host is preparing the test buffers, so time shall be frozen while host emulates hardware.

I know that this will lead to a big drift between host and guest time, but I am OK with that.

Is there any way on which I can prevent KVM/QEMU from compensating/synchronziing time? I saw that modern kernels includes a parameter "-no-kvmclock" but is not clear to me if that is indeed for wnat I need. Some advices?

Thanks to all for support.

Juan

Comment: 9 Month have passed and there is still no solution for this question. But for a small circle this question is for value. So have you figured out how to actually do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up.. Didn’t find a solution..,

Comment: It is a very good question and QEMU managing the time between host and guest still confuses me. I want to understand is it possible to test real time scenarios with QEMU or do timing analysis tests with QEMU for a hardware? If yes, how does QEMU manage to do that?